# TFS 2010 TF50309 view collection-level information

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-power-tools

The server is tfs2010.  The client is visual studio 2012 and tfs power tools 2012.

I tried to run this command:

```
C:\> witadmin exportwitd /collection:http://pi-dev-tfs01:8080/tfs /p:SAP /n:Task
TF50309: The following account does not have sufficient permissions to complete the operation: 
ALTERIAN\Eric Hartford. The following permissions are needed to perform this operation: 
View collection-level information.
```

However when I look at the security permissions and the group membership, it all looks good.
[image: security settings]

Any idea why would it produce this error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your collection Uri is the server location, not the Project Collection.

it should read:

> `witadmin exportwitd /collection:http://pi-dev-tfs01:8080/tfs/SM2 /p:SAP /n:Task`